# HTML "picture in picture"

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to create a (preferably) HTML code that would load content from another, small page into the current website. The content of the small page is to be a set of anchors with images that change dynamically (thus encoding them into the page where they are to be displayed would not be practical). Is such a functionality achievable in pure HTML, or do I need to use javascript? Can someone provide a sample code of how it would look like?

Comment: I would use jquery .load method: [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your first HTML page

```
<iframe src="small-page.html" />
```

This creates a box on your first HTML page containing the contents of your second page.

You can control the height, width as well as other styles on the IFRAME.